# Custom Domain SSL for azure blob

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Anyone can find a workaround for having custom domain pointing to azure blob? Can application gateway pointed to there? how?
Facts :
- Azure blob does not support custom domain for SSL
- Using custom domain with SSL will prompt security concern due to the assets is from different SSL cert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Currently there is no support for custom domains with SSL on Azure Storage services.

[Give your vote here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/3007732-make-it-possible-to-use-ssl-on-blob-storage-using) to help get this prioritised!

Comment: I did. The idea has been there for 2 years. I do not know how long to wait since its business critical for me as well. I think Amazon can do that with S3.

Comment: You can still use the HTTPS endpoint for blobs. Using Microsoft provided and secured endpoint does not compromise security in any context.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Application Gateway with my custom SSL to access BLOB.

1. Create a Application Gateway instance.
2. Add your custom SSL inside the SSL Settings in the App Gateway.
3. Configure backend pool and listener in App gateway.
4. Create a container and upload an image into it, copy the image URL. Replace the image domain BLOB URL with the Application Gateway IP. Request the image.

For retrieving sensitive files: Once you get the image, remember to turn off the *Allow Blob public access* toggle in your Storage Account settings.